# Ссылки на php страницы через Gulp

Tags: php, html, html5, gulp, browsersync

Не получается проходить по ссылкам (на php файлы) при работе через Gulp. Вот отрывок кода файла gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    browserSync     = require('browser-sync');
...

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
     browserSync({ 
      proxy: 'site.gulp/app',
        });
    });
...
```

Ссылки с главной страницы выглядят следующим образом:

```
<a href="/uslugi-i-tsenyi" itemprop="url" title="Услуги и цены ">
```

Не получается заставить их работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Необходимо было дописать к ссылкам доменное имя вот так (указать полный путь):

```
<a href="http://site.gulp/app/uslugi-i-tsenyi" itemprop="url" title="Услуги и цены ">
```

Ну и конечно же прописать редиректы для чпу, вот пример файла .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /app/?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```